# how to specify .bib file location when working on the same .tex file synced between mac and win

Tags: bibliographies

My bibliography file is put in my Dropbox that syncs on my mac and PC like `Dropbox/Library/Library.bib` and my .tex source file is in `Dropbox/article1/manuscript/manuscript.tex` and I use `\bibliography{../../Library/Library}` such as relative path in my .tex source file.

it works well on PC (with texlive 2017) while can not find the bib file on my mac.

How can I specify a bib file smartly in the same tex?

Comment: I cannot really imagine this works on any device as your `..` seem to lead to the parent folder of the `Dropbox` directory.

Comment: this indeed works on my PC wih windows 10

Comment: I just did a quick test on Ubuntu (without Dropbox sync, but the given directory structure): It does not work as is, but replacing `\bibliography{../../../library/Library}` with `\bibliography{./../../Library/Library}` or `\bibliography{../../Library/Library}` works. (The second problem is that Windows is case-insensitive, while Unix-like systems are case-sensitive.)

Comment: sorry there are some typos, the original question has been corrected and updated, what I say indeed works is for \bibliography{../../Library/Library}

Answer (score 1):

problem resolved

the reason is I specified output directory in latemkrc

there seems a bug for bibtex？

anyway

by changing
    `\bibliography{../../Library/Library}`
to 
    `\bibliography{output/../../../Library/Library}`

where output is apparently the name of my output folder under working directory